# Is this a correct use of "optimal"?

Tags: classification, optimization, terminology

During fine-tuning some classifier parameters, is it correct to talk about "optimal" configuration?

For example, if perfect classification is impossible, but the error converges to some relatively good small value, is it correct to call it an "optimal" solution, or is it "suboptimal" because there's no single optimal one?

If there are several configurations that perform best and equally good, would it be correct to call either of them "optimal"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Optimal", "Best", "Equally good", are all concepts *relative* to some criterion. Once you specify your criterion, the ranking of alternative configurations can be determined, and the first in rank will be *optimal according to the specific criterion* -no more than that.

And it so happens that in most cases, a configuration optimal given criterion A, is not optimal given criterion B.

If, given the same criterion, two alternative configurations "perform equally well", then, strictly speaking, they are both "optimal" -although if the criterion is some continuous quantity, it will be difficult for the two to perform *exactly* the same. Still, in practice, if their performance according always to the same criterion is "very close" (vague term), then we usually say that they are "equivalent" in terms of predictive or explanatory power.

Finally, the criterion is not "achieve the ideal" (say, zero error), but "how close to the ideal can you be" (minimum error).

Comment: Thank you! This answers all my questions. 
(I was thinking about the criterion but was not sure)

Comment: If the criterion is evaluating prediction/classification performance in someway and the two different configurations yield similar results then the configuration with least complexity should be preferred. This involves lower number of parameters, simpler functional forms, and integer coefficients over long decimal point coefficients.